# Running sass from cpanel

Tags: sass, cpanel

I have installed the ruby gem for sass, but have no idea how to run the `sass --watch stylesheets/sass:stylesheets/compiled` command. Is it even possible using cpanel since I don't have access to the command line.

Comment: I would compile Sass locally on your development machine.

Comment: Out of curiosity. Why don't you have access to command line? You should be able to get Shell access through your webhost. It is usually under the Security section in cpanel.

Comment: @KrisHollenbeck Its through hostgator on a shared server, so I don't get shell access.

Comment: You could maybe try writing a shell script with your watch commands and executing it with PHP.